# Given $P(H2|H1)$, $P(T2|T1)$, $P(H_1)$, $P(T_1)$. Find $P(T_2)$.

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics

Suppose $P(H2|H1)=.7$ and $P(T2|T1)=.5$ where we are either in an $H$ situation
or a $T$ situation (heads or tails) and the subscript refer to the first or second 
trial. We also know that $P(H1)=.5=P(T1)$

Let $T2$ be the event of a tail on the second trail. What is $P(T_2)$?

Please someone help me with this problem. What formula do I use for this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Simply, The different trials are independent events. Thus $P(A|B)=P(A).P(B)$

Comment: @TheDeadLegend They are not independent in this example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the law of total probability:
$$\begin{align}P(T_2)&=P(T_2|T_1)P(T_1)+P(T_2|H_1)P(H_1)\\&=P(T_2|T_1)P(T_1)+(1-P(H_2|H_1))P(H_1)\\&=0.5\cdot0.5+(1-0.7)\cdot0.5\\&=0.4\end{align}$$

Comment: Where do I get a list of all laws of  probability?

Comment: In this question I used [_the law of total probability_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability) - this is very useful when dealing with conditional probability, as it can help you split up the conditional probability into other parts which you know. There are many other useful laws too, you can probably find the ones you need in your text books or lecture notes.